# How can I run a batch file when closing a console (like user-profile.cmd but for exiting)?

Tags: conemu

I've been using JPSoft's Take Command for years as my cmd replacement, and it uses a `TCStart.bat` for startup and a `TCExit.bat` for shutdown, which I use to persistently store and retrieve some state information.

I'm trying to go full ConEmu but so far I haven't been able to setup a shutdown script.

Is it possible to do so?

Comment: Just use tcc.exe inside ConEmu?

Comment: I started by using tcc inside ConEmu, but I want the clink enhancements and clink doesn't seem to be working with TCC, so I'd rather try the other way around.